# Forwarding contact via SMS Ubuntu BQ Aquaris 4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, contacts, sms

I have a new Ubuntu Aquaris 4.5. I am looking for a way of forwarding a contact in my address book to another contact via a text message. Can't seem to find a simple way to forward a contact via SMS either in the Messaging menu or in the contacts menu. Have to manually enter contact details into a message

Thanks for all the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Open the contact you want to share > Click on Share > Choose Messaging app > Enter number/contact you want to send the first contact to and click on send.

The sending works. The contact is sent as an MMS.

Sharing via QR code (Tagger app) is possible as well.

Comment: Does not work. Keep getting the message "Sending failed"

Comment: @user4641490 It does send as MMS and not as SMS, depending on your provider you may have to activate this service.